# Melhores práticas na interação entre Activities

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout, revisão-de-código

Estou desenvolvendo um aplicativo apenas para validar a interação entre `activities` através de `intents`.

Criei 5 `ImageButton` com uma imagem para cada um. Cada botão representa um filme e caso o usuário clique em algum deles, é direcionado para uma nova `activity` com a sinopse do filme. Na `activity` com a sinopse, existe um "`up navigation`" que retorna a `activity` principal (home).

A forma como eu desenvolvi deixou o projeto muito extenso pois criei 6 `activities` (`MainActivity` e 5 `activities`, uma para cada filme) e 6 `layouts`. Além disso, meu apk está com 1,5mb.

Alguém poderia me ajudar com sugestões de melhores práticas para eu minimizar meu código ou a forma como desenvolvi está correta e poderia ser desenvolvida num aplicativo real?

**Minha MainActivity**

```
package luizugliano.com.br.appfilmes;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

}

public void onClickBtVideo01(View view){
    Intent intent = new Intent(getContext(),ActivityVideo01.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}

public void onClickBtVideo02(View view){
    Intent intent = new Intent(getContext(),ActivityVideo02.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}

public void onClickBtVideo03(View view){
    Intent intent = new Intent(getContext(),ActivityVideo03.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}

public void onClickBtVideo04(View view){
    Intent intent = new Intent(getContext(),ActivityVideo04.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}

public void onClickBtVideo05(View view){
    Intent intent = new Intent(getContext(),ActivityVideo05.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}

private Context getContext(){
    return this;
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
}
```

**Minha ActivityVideo01** (As outras activities possuem o mesmo código então eu colocarei somente essa como exemplo)

```
package luizugliano.com.br.appfilmes;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.MenuItem;

public class ActivityVideo01 extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_activity_video01);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == android.R.id.home) {
        //O método finish encerrará essa activity
        finish();
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

}
```

**Meu content_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
tools:showIn="@layout/activity_main" tools:context=".MainActivity">

<TextView android:text="Sinopse - Filmes" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:textSize="22dp"/>

<HorizontalScrollView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/layout_marginTop">

    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="@dimen/layout_width"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/layout_height"
        android:id="@+id/imageButton01"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:background="@drawable/btn_img_01"
        android:onClick="onClickBtVideo01"/>

    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="@dimen/layout_width"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/layout_height"
        android:id="@+id/imageButton02"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/layout_marginLeft"
        android:background="@drawable/btn_img_02"
        android:onClick="onClickBtVideo02"/>

    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="@dimen/layout_width"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/layout_height"
        android:id="@+id/imageButton03"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/layout_marginLeft"
        android:background="@drawable/btn_img_03"
        android:onClick="onClickBtVideo03"/>

    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="@dimen/layout_width"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/layout_height"
        android:id="@+id/imageButton04"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/layout_marginLeft"
        android:background="@drawable/btn_img_04"
        android:onClick="onClickBtVideo04"/>

    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="@dimen/layout_width"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/layout_height"
        android:id="@+id/imageButton05"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/layout_marginLeft"
        android:background="@drawable/btn_img_05"
        android:onClick="onClickBtVideo05"/>

</LinearLayout>
</HorizontalScrollView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

**Meu content_activity_video01.xml** (Os outros layouts possuem o mesmo código então eu colocarei somente esse como exemplo )

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
tools:showIn="@layout/activity_activity_video01"
tools:context="luizugliano.com.br.appfilmes.ActivityVideo01">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
    android:text="Title Synopsis"
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
    android:text="Synopsis"
    android:id="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_marginTop="51dp"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Acho que fica melhor se você usar um DB na sua aplicação. Os dados dos filmes, ficam salvos no DB e, quando o usuário tocar em algum botão da activity principal, iria chamar uma outra activity e, nela, você leria os dados do DB. Com isso, eliminaria 4 activity's iguais.

Comment: 2 atividades chegam perfeitamente para isso, uma para a lista de filmes e outra para a sinopse. Guardando tudo na BD como disse o @emanuelsn.

Comment: Luiz, para saber se a pergunta é on-topic ou não, é só conferir a [help]. Ou então, pode perguntar no [meta] ou no [chat].

Comment: Muito obrigado pela informação @brasofilo

Comment: Obrigado @emanuelsn

Comment: Obrigado @JorgeB.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Você tem 5 activitys iguais. E você pode melhorar isso.

Hoje, você exibe apenas a Sinopse do filme. 
Já imaginou se você precisar exibir, além da sinopse, os atores principais?
Você precisaria ir em cada uma das 5 activitys e adicionar essa informação lá.

### O que pode ser feito para melhorar?

- Você pode tem necessidade de apenas 2 Activitys: Uma principal, para listar os filmes, e uma outra para exibir a sinopse deles
- Você pode trabalhar com o Banco de Dados (por exemplo o SQLite); 
  Quando o usuário tocar em um filme, você abre a activity de sinopse passando como parâmetro o ID/Nome do filme. E nessa activity de sinopses, você apenas carrega os dados do filme.
- Você disse ter 5 botões na sua Activity principal. Se você quiser adicionar outros filmes, iria precisar ficar incluindo mais botões.

  Seria mais interessante, ter a lista de filmes disponíveis, em uma Lista, visando essa possibilidade de se adicionar mais filmes.

---

Recomendo que você leia:

[SQLite - Android](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/package-summary.html)

[Página oficial do SQLite](https://www.sqlite.org/)

[SQLite no Android. Entendendo e Utilizando](http://www.thiengo.com.br/sqlite-no-android-entendendo-e-utilizando)

Answer (score 2):

Para deixar o seu aplicativo menor e com uma fluidez melhor na transição e exibição das telas, recomendo que você utilize a combinação **[Activity + Fragments](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/index.html)**.

Os Fragments podem ser entendidos como uma *sub Activity*, ou seja, uma pequena tela que pode ser inserida dentro de uma Activity principal. A vantagem de se utilizar fragments, é que eles podem ser (re)utilizados para criar interfaces mais dinamicas, como [Navigation Drawer](https://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html) e [Swipe Views](http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/swipe-views.html).

Baseando-se nessas dicas e analisando o seu caso, creio que o ideal 
seria você fazer o seguinte:

- Criar uma Activity( *e.g MainActivity*) principal que gerencia os fragments
- Criar um Fragment( *e.g. FragmentFilmes*) que mostra os filmes
- Criar um Fragment( *e.g. FragmentDetalhes*) que mostra os detalhes dos filmes

Assim, ao iniciar, a MainActivity mostraria o fragment FragmentFilmes, que teria uma lista( ou qualquer outra forma de exibição) de filmes e caso você clicasse em algum filme, a MainActivity chamaria o fragment FragmentDetalhes, contendo os detalhes do filme selecionado.

É importante seguir também a dica do @emanuelsn , que sugeriu a criação de um banco de dados contendo as informações dos filmes, pois assim, você pode carregar as informações dos filmes dinamicamente no FragmentDetalhes, eliminando a necessidade de ter um fragment com textos fixos.

Uma outra sugestão é seguir [as regras do Material Design](https://www.google.com/design/spec/patterns/navigation.html#) para a criação de navegação entre telas.